# Returning pointer to a class variable in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm currently writing lab work for my study, and I'd like to make a function return a pointer to the variable from the same class.

```
int* getProc(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1:
                return &this.proc1tasks;
                break;
            case 2:
                return &this.proc2tasks;
                break;
        }
    }
```

But for every `&this.proc#tasks` VS 2013 says

> Error 2   Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Is there any way to make it work as I imagined?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do: go read about the `unsafe` keyword.

Comment: Yes. Use an unsafe context, as the error message indicates. More to the point though is _why_ do you want to do this? There are alternatives that would work in safe code, but without more context it's not practical to try to guess what you really want.

Comment: Actually, I have five such variables in this class and based on the function parameter I wanted to return pointer to one of that variables to use it in further operations. Will it work if I enable unsafe code in project settings? And as far as I understand unsafe must be always used when I use pointers in C3 code?

Comment: You just don't want to actually use pointers here; you want to use managed constructs to accomplish a goal that you would normally use pointers for in another language like C/C++.

Comment: _I'd like to make a function return a pointer_ That may be true. But do you __like__ to because you actually __need__ it or do you just __think__ it is the way because you don't know about regular C#/.NET programming??

Comment: By using `unsafe`, you're telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, leave me alone." If you *don't* know what you're doing (hint: there are other, *much* better ways of accomplishing your underlying intent...) then don't lie to the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this way as I'd do like this in C/C++ and I don't know better option in .Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the method return a delegate that, when invoked, will evaluate the value of the variable in question:

```
public Func<int> getProc(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            return () => proc1tasks;
        case 2:
            return () => proc2tasks;
    }
}
```

This will provide you with an object which, when invoked (much like with a pointer you would dereference), will give you the current value of that field.

Comment: I like this much better than the *unsafe* way.